# How to create a group email address on Google Workspace

Tags: email, google-workspace

I manage a Google Workspace account for a small organisation. Let's say their domain is example.com. Previously they had an alias set up so that mail sent to hello@example.com would be forwarded to (for example) jenny@example.com. Now they want emails sent to hello@example.com to be forwarded to both jenny@example.com and greg@example.com. How do I set that up? It seems that every time I (infrequently) log into the admin area, Google have renamed or moved everything. The original alias doesn't show up as an alias on the jenny@example.com account, so I'm guessing it was done by another means, perhaps a catch-all, but I can't find any evidence of existing routing rules either. I haven't been able to find up to date instructions on how to get a list of active email addresses or current routing rules. First I need to see what we've already got, then I need to figure out whether that setup will work with changes, or whether we need to use a different approach. I don't want to blindly go in and just add a new rule according to the latest instructions without understanding how the configuration works at the moment, because I'm scared it will break itself somehow.

I used to think that Microsoft were bad for moving everything around every few years, but Google have taken it to the next level! All of the existing configuration was done when it was still G Suite, or possibly even Google Apps, and with each rebrand all the terminology has changed...

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful to anyone else, I resolved this by trawling through email conversations to find notes from when the original alias was set up, and confirmed from there that it was done by means of a catch-all on the domain forwarding all messages sent to unrecognised addresses on to jenny@example.com. From there I added a filter rule on the jenny@example.com account, forwarding to greg@example.com when To = hello@example.com. Very clunky, but there you go.